# Django complains about field not being unique on editing an entry

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

models.py

```
class SwagKey(BaseModel):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False)
    keytype = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="tshirt")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, default=0)
```

admin.py

```
class SwagForm(ModelForm):
    keytype = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices = ([('tshirt','tshirt'), ('jacket','jacket'),('backpack','backpack'), ]), initial='3', required = True,)
    class Meta:
        model = SwagKey

class SwagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['key','keytype', 'user']
    fieldsets = [
        ("Keys",        {"fields": ['key', 'keytype']}),
        ("User",        {"fields": ['user']})
    ]
    form = SwagForm


admin.site.register(SwagKey, SwagAdmin)
```

When I create an entry its all fine and dandy. However, when I try to edit to assign the "key" to a user, it complains about "Swag key with this Key already exists.", even though this is the only entry using this key. How can I make this field unique but not complain if I update any of its fields? Thanks!

Comment: What's does your BaseModel look like?

Comment: can you post the exact error message with the exception type too?

Comment: The BaseModel can be found here: https://github.com/Syerram/osqa/blob/master/forum/models/base.py

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing this issue with OSQA's BaseModel class, source can be found here:
https://github.com/Syerram/osqa/blob/master/forum/models/base.py

Comment: Error is: Swag key with this Key already exists.  It doesn't throw an exception, simply prevents the form from submitting.